# SocketScan Getting the Battery Level in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, socketscan

Whatever I seem to try I cannot currently get back the Battery level from the iOS/SocketScan API.  I am using version 10.3.36, here is my code so far:

```
func onDeviceArrival(result: SKTRESULT, device deviceInfo: DeviceInfo!) {
    print("onDeviceArrival:\(deviceInfo.getName())")
scanApiHelper.postGetBattery(deviceInfo, target: self, response: #selector(onGetBatteryInfo))

}

func onGetBatteryInfo(scanObj: ISktScanObject) {

    let result:SKTRESULT = scanObj.Msg().Result()
    print("GetBatteryInfo status:\(result)")

    if (result == ESKT_NOERROR) {
        let batterylevel = scanObj.Property().getUlong()
        print("Battery is:\(batterylevel)")
    } else {
        print("Error GetBatteryInfo status:\(result)")
    }
```

However, the values I get back are:

```
GetBatteryInfo status:0

Battery is:1677741312
```

If my code is correct then how do I make the Battery result I get back a meaningful result, like a percentage?
  If I'm way off then how do I get back info like the battery level, firmware version etc?

Thanks

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: `SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL` isn't supported in Swift. However, the [docs](http://www.socketmobile.com/docs/default-source/developer-documentation/scanapi.pdf?sfvrsn=2) explain that the battery level response includes the min, current and max levels encoded in the first, second and third bytes, respectively.

The following is equivalent to using `SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL`

**Swift**

```
func onGetBatteryInfo(scanObj: ISktScanObject) {

    let result:SKTRESULT = scanObj.Msg().Result()

    if(SKTSUCCESS(result)){

        let batteryInfo = scanObj.Property().getUlong();

        let batteryMin = ((batteryInfo >> 4) & 0xff);
        let batteryCurrent = ((batteryInfo >> 8) & 0xff);
        let batteryMax = ((batteryInfo >> 12) & 0xff);

        let batteryPercentage = batteryCurrent / (batteryMax - batteryMin);
        print("Battery is:\(batteryPercentage)")

        self.setBatteryLevel = batteryPercentage
        self.tableView.reloadData

    } else {

        print("Error GetBatteryInfo status:\(result)")
    }
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
-(void) onGetBatteryInfo:(ISktScanObject*)scanObj {

SKTRESULT result=[[scanObj Msg]Result];
if(SKTSUCCESS(result)){

    long batteryLevel = SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL([[scanObj Property] getUlong]);
    NSLog(@"BatteryInfo %ld", batteryLevel);

    [self setBatteryLevel:batteryLevel];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

} else {

    NSLog(@"Error GetBatteryInfo status: %ld",result);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's exactly what I thought, but in Swift as far as I can see it knows nothing about SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL, you can't use SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL as you get use of unresolved identifer. that's why I am stuck as according to the documentation it should be fine!

Comment: @Dave I edited tymac's answer to inline the code for `SKTBATTERY_GETCURLEVEL` because you are right, that is a `#define` macro which doesn't exist in the swift version

Comment: Thanks @Enrico. As noted I translated it from Objective-C. Actually I have an open ticket with SocketScan myself as I need to ask them about something else. Dave if you want to use their native class method you can just write an Objective-C 'extension'. I added the Objective-C incase you want it. Enrico's use of bitwise masking to get the percentage equivalent is amazing :)

Comment: Hi Guys that is brilliant!  Works a treat, thanks so much for your help, I would not have got that working in a million years otherwise!!!! Awesome stuff, thanks!!!

Comment: Glad we could help you out. Good luck in your project @Dave.

Comment: I just found out that Enrico is from the SocketScan Dev Team so this is totally official. lol Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code I use. Theres a variable defined in appDelegate for the batteryPercentage, and that is read when the v value is needed. The value is updated each 120 seconds by a timer, this way actions can occur as the level drops etc.

```
 func onBatteryLevel (scanObj: ISktScanObject) {
    let result: SKTRESULT = scanObj.Msg().Result()
    if (SKTRESULT(result) > -1) {
        let property: ISktScanProperty = scanObj.Property()
        var batteryLevel = property.getUlong()

        #if arch(x86_64) || arch(arm64)
            batteryLevel = (batteryLevel<<(48))>>(56)
            #else
            batteryLevel = (batteryLevel<<(48-32))>>(56-32)
        #endif
        batteryPercentage = Int(batteryLevel)
    } else {
        debug ("data error \(result)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 4** I just came across this problem and came up with the following solution.

```
var lastDeviceConnected : CaptureHelperDevice? {

    didSet {

        guard let lastDevice = self.lastDeviceConnected else { return }
        lastDevice.getBatteryLevelWithCompletionHandler { result, batteryLevel in

            guard result == SKTResult.E_NOERROR, let batteryLevel = batteryLevel else { return }

            let minimum = SKTHelper.getMinimumLevel(fromBatteryLevel: Int(batteryLevel))
            let maximum = SKTHelper.getMaximumLevel(fromBatteryLevel: Int(batteryLevel))
            let current = SKTHelper.getCurrentLevel(fromBatteryLevel: Int(batteryLevel))

            print("minimum: \(minimum)")
            print("maximum: \(maximum)")
            print("current: \(current)")

            // current is out battery level in %
            // minimum and maximum could for example be used for 
            // for a slider or something that visually presents
            // the battery status
        }
    }
}
```

In my example I'm **not** handling the case that there could be no device or that the battery status might not have been retrieved as expected. I simply `guard / return`. In your example you might want to handle the issue.